# Instantiated UI element references to the same object

Tags: unity, c#

I'm creating UI using a prefab and move it using a coroutine, the prefab has `transform.position` of `(0,0,0)`:

```
private List<GameObject> liveBoxes = new List<GameObject>();

void Update()
{
  PopDialogBoxFixedInterval();
}

// @todo debug only
void PopDialogBoxFixedInterval()
{
  float now = Time.time;
  if (now - lastTime > delay)
  {
    lastTime = now;
    PopDialogBox();
  }
}

void PopDialogBox()
{
  Vector3 pos = new Vector3(-horzExtent + .5f, -vertExtent, 0f);
  GameObject box = Instantiate(dialogBoxPrefab, pos, Quaternion.identity, canvas.transform);

  box.name = "Box_" + Time.time;
  liveBoxes.Add(box);

  for (int i = 0; i < liveBoxes.Count; ++i)
  {
    Debug.Log("Move " + liveBoxes[i].name + ", all: " + liveBoxes.Count);
    StartCoroutine(SmoothMoveDialogBox(liveBoxes[i]));
  }
}
```

The problem is the `box` always references to the first created object. As the below:

[image]

But in fact I have more than one boxes (adding "Box_2" is not shown in log):

[image]

---

The prefab itself is a panel with text and image:

[image]

Comment: I think more information is needed, the code here does not seem to do something strange at all, you are adding new instances to the list (I mention it because it is a common mistake that one tries to manipulate the prefab instead, but this is not the case). It would be useful for we to help you if you also provided the script that makes the debugs, and maybe the one that makes the PopDialogBox(Vector3) call.

Comment: @LinkWindcrafter Thanks so much! I occasionally found if I resize the game window, they sometimes move. Should I still provide full code?

Comment: If your problem were to persist, yes, so anyone here may be able to help you.

Comment: @LinkWindcrafter Thanks. Full code is posted.

Comment: ok, from what I can see, after 'x' delay has ellapsed, you instantiate a box, and name it with the ellapsed time as sufix to identify it. It may be possible that the PopDialogeBox() method is just called once, but that depends on delay's value and if you initialize lastTime  as Time.time on either Awake or Start (so the first time it checks on Update there is no time difference). Or...where does the debug happen? inside the coroutine or in a script contained on the prefab?

Comment: @LinkWindcrafter `Move Box_` is the line in `PopDialogBox`'s for-loop, and `Box_.. from..to..` is in the coroutine.

Comment: Ok. It seems the debug shown on console is less that the one declared on the for loop. Maybe you could try clicking that log so the full debug is shown? If not, maybe it could be on the coroutine itself, on in another script that may be clearing the list?

Comment: @LinkWindcrafter It's the only script in the scene. The objects persist, but they don't move. Stepping through breakpoints show they reference `transform.position` as prefab's / previously created one's. I'm modifying the Debug log lines but I didn't touch other lines.

Comment: Try to debug the list's count before the loop, but after the new box is added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92955/discussion-between-knh190-and-linkwindcrafter).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by canvas render mode which I used "screenspace - camera", so it doesn't move the elements under it.

The default configuration is "screenspace - overlap" and won't cause any trouble. This is not an optimal answer since I don't understand why. But it solved the problem I had.